# Make bootstrap grid look like a table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a nice table layout but I wanna make it responsive using bootstrap row, col.

Excuse me for using images but is for illustrating the purpose.

This is how the table looks like:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g527I.png)

It's a standard html table with tr and td; but when try to use bootstrap with the first 2 rows and this code:

```
<div class="row like-table" style="background-color:#f9f9f9;">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="txt_first_name">First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="txt_first_name" id="txt_first_name" value="<?php echo $var_FirstName;?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="txt_last_name">Last Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="txt_last_name" id="txt_last_name" value="<?php echo $var_LastName;?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <select name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="" <?php if($var_Gender==''){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Please Select</option>
            <option value="Male" <?php if($var_Gender=='Male'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Male</option>
            <option value="Female" <?php if($var_Gender=='Female'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Female</option>
            <option value="Other" <?php if($var_Gender=='Other'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't get a neat table but this:

[table bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olqEX.png)

It seems like col-md-1 is too narrow and col-md-2 is to wide for the first column and the labels are not properly align. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want 3 columns with labels and inputs.
What you can do is this:

```
<div class="row like-table">
 <div class="col-md-4">
<div class="col-md-6"><label for="txt_first_name">First Name</label></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" value="FirstName">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6"><label for="txt_birth_date">Birth Date</label></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" value="">
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-6"><label for="txt_last_name">Last Name</label>
 </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><label for="txt_birth_date">Hire Date</label>
 </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-6"><label for="gender">Gender</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><select>
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="Male" >Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><label for="txt_termination_date">Termination Date</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" value="">
  </div>
   </div>


  </div>
```